# Understanding a one-to-many relationship with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I have a table `users` with primary index `userId`. Currently, each user has a field `arrayOfRelatedUserIds`, so that any one user can have a relationship with several other `users`. (It's an `array` in `JSON` format). This I know to be not the best solution, and there are better ways of doing this, but I'm just not understanding how. How would I do this without an array? What's the "legit" method of designing this so that each `user` be related to several `users` at once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create another table `related_users` with 2 columns:

1. `userId`
2. `related_userId`

And store each relation as a row

Comment: @OZ_: composite primary key of `(userId, related_userId)` would help avoiding artificial keys here

Comment: `ID` key gives ability to write pure CRUD, whithout "WHERE .. AND ..", so I prefer to have ID in all entities.

Comment: @OZ_: indeed. Well, both solutions have their pros and cons and this is a bit irrelevant to the question ;-)